# jQuery escape white spaces

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, escaping

Inside the selectmenu from https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui I have set a title for each option do be displayed as an icon. Working fine except the icons which filename contains white space. No icon is shown if the file name is like `African Union.png`

the jquery:

```
        $('select.flags').selectmenu({
            icons: [
                {find: '.icon'}
            ],
            bgImage: function() {
                return 'url(' + $(this).attr("title") + ')';
            }
        });
```

html:

```
<option value="African Union.png" class="icon" title="/img/icons/flags/African Union.png" >African Union</option>
```

If I am not able to get it working inside the jQuery - How to escape the white spaces using php? Is the `str_replace` the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[URLs in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#uri) can either be unquoted or quoted in single or double quotes. If unquoted, as in your case, you need to escape certain characters:

> Some characters appearing in an unquoted URI, such as parentheses, white space characters, single quotes (`'`) and double quotes (`"`), must be escaped with a backslash so that the resulting URI value is a URI token: '`\(`', '`\)`'.

So:

```
'url(' + $(this).attr("title").replace(/(?=[()\s'"])/g, '\\') + ')'
```

Or you put the URL in quotes, preferably double quotes as [plain single quotes are allowed in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/53114):

```
'url("' + $(this).attr("title") + '")'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode). You can't have spaces in a URL in the first place.

```
$filename = "African Union.png";
$url = urlencode($filename);
$html_safe_url = htmlspecialchars($url);

echo "<option value='$html_safe_url' class='icon' title='/img/icons/flags/$html_safe_url'>African Union</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$("#text_box_id").change(function() {
var name = $(this).val();
var dname_without_space = $("#text_box_id").val().replace(/ /g, "");
var name_without_special_char =      dname_without_space.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, "");
$(this).attr("value", name_without_special_char );
});
```

It will remove white space as well as special characters.
see this post

http://patelmilap.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/using-jquery-remove-space-special-characters-while-typing/